# moving files in subdirectories up one (and *only* one) level

Tags: bash, directory, mv, subdirectory

i am trying to move files nested in subdirectories up exactly one level. i am in os x terminal, and am new to bash. i'm fairly certain this is simple, i just don't know how to do it.

i want to change a file structure that looks like this:

```
~/container
       /1-A
           LEVEL 1 - 000.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 001.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 002.jpg
       /1-B
           /2-A
               LEVEL 2 - 007.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 008.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 009.jpg
       /1-C
           LEVEL 1 - 003.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 004.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 005.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 006.jpg
       /1-D
           /2-C
               LEVEL 2 - 010.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 011.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 012.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 013.jpg
               LEVEL 2 - 014.jpg
       /1-E
           LEVEL 1 - 015.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 016.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 017.jpg
       /1-F
           /2-B
               /3-A
                   LEVEL 3 - 018.jpg
                   LEVEL 3 - 019.jpg
                   LEVEL 3 - 020.jpg
                   LEVEL 3 - 021.jpg
```

to one that looks like this:

```
~/container
       /1-A
           LEVEL 1 - 000.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 001.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 002.jpg
       /1-B
           LEVEL 2 - 007.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 008.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 009.jpg
           /2-A
       /1-C
           LEVEL 1 - 003.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 004.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 005.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 006.jpg
       /1-D
           LEVEL 2 - 010.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 011.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 012.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 013.jpg
           LEVEL 2 - 014.jpg
           /2-C
       /1-E
           LEVEL 1 - 015.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 016.jpg
           LEVEL 1 - 017.jpg
       /1-F
           /2-B
               LEVEL 3 - 018.jpg
               LEVEL 3 - 019.jpg
               LEVEL 3 - 020.jpg
               LEVEL 3 - 021.jpg 
               /3-A
```

i have tried:

```
find ~/container  -mindepth 3 -type f -exec mv {} . \;
```

and

```
find ~/container  -mindepth 3 -type f -exec mv {} .. \;
```

but these move the files in relation to the root directory, not the directory the file itself is in. in other words, they move the files too far up. i want them to move up EXACTLY one level, however deeply nested they are to begin with.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

This should solve your problem:

```
find ~/container -mindepth 3 -type f -execdir mv "{}" ./.. \;
```

Description:
`find ~/container` search inside this folder.
`-mindepth 3` show only files that are 3 directories down.
`-type f` show only files (not directories).
`-execdir` execute the following command on each file inside its directory.
`mv "{}" ./..` move the file one directory up.
`\;` repeat a new command for each file selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~/container  -mindepth 3 -type f | xargs -i bash -c 'mv "{}" $(dirname "{}")/..'
```

For each file it finds dirname of it and moves it one level up.

** update **

with GNU find...

```
find ~/container  -mindepth 3 -type f  -execdir mv "{}" $(dirname "{}")/.. \;
```

while loop...

```
find ~/container  -mindepth 3 -type f | while read file; do
     mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/.."
done
```

Comment: thanks! it's still not working for me, though. when i try, i get this message:

`xargs: illegal option -- i
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
`

Comment: you may be using older xargs. Try `xargs -I {} mv "{}" $(dirname "{}")/..`

Comment: the while loop is doing the trick. thanks so much! if you're willing, i'd love to know how the syntax for "$(dirname "$file")/.." works.

Comment: $() is syntax to run command in subshell. dirname filename will return the parent directory of file and .. will move up one level from there